# Return to previous category from single page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have next code on my single page.

```
  // RETURN TO PREVIOUS CATEGORY
  $('.cross').on('click', function(){
    var toPrevPage = $(this);
        toPrevPage = history.back();
  });
```

When you go to single page through urlOfsite/ => urlOfsite/category => urlOfsite/category/singlePage and then click on cross - you will be returned to the category from which you came, but when you go to single page through direct link - the cross does not return to the previous category.
Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

[live example](http://beardhouse.com.ua/art/slider)

Comment: because history.back(); is make browser go to the previous page in history but if  it was a direct link there is no previous page...

You should find  another way to go back, for example manually cat off part of the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you:

```
$('.cross').on('click', function(){
    var url_parts = window.location.href.split('/');
    //remove last one part
    url_parts.pop();
    // redirect to top level of category
    window.location.href = url_parts.join('/');
});
```